# error in declaration of array in merge sort problem

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a code which is showing me error in allocating size to array. I don't think I have made a mistake.

I tried the code in "CODEBLOCKS" which gave me my output but when I perform this in "Visual Studio" I get some errors.

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;
    int L[n1];
    int R[n2];
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

The expected result was to get a sorted array
but the actual output is:

```
1.error C2057: expected constant expression
2.error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
3.error C2133: 'L' : unknown size
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to include a copy-paste (in full, complete, and as text) of the error. And add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: However, are you sure you're building a ***C*** source code? It's not C++? What is the full name of the source file? And which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: In addition, `int L[n1];` is a VLA which requires a compiler made this millennium. So Visual Studio in C mode might not be up for the task, depending on version. Most Visual Studio 201x are from the year 1990.